# How get properties of one class without custom class types

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, properties, getproperties

I have a Person class :

```
public class Person 
{
    virtual public long Code { get; set; }
    virtual public string Title { get; set; }       
    virtual public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I need to a generic solution for get all properties of Person class without properties by custom class types. Means select `Code` , `Title` properties.

```
typeof(Person).GetProperties();           //Title , Code , Employee
typeof(Person).GetProperties().Where(x => !x.PropertyType.IsClass); // Code
```

How can I select all properties without custom class types? (`Code` , `Title`)

Comment: Does "custom type" imply that 3rd party assemblies are custom or are you just looking for types that aren't "yours"?

Comment: One dilemma here: there is no inbuilt definition of "custom class types", and indeed, `Title` is a `string,` which *is a class* (so you can't just use `.IsClass`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to check the [`ScopeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.scopename) of the [`Module`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.module) of the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):

```
typeof(Person).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.Module.ScopeName == "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary")
```

since there is no direct way that to tell if a type is built-in or not.

To get some other ideas, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114799/is-there-a-function-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-builtin-data-type), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932580/how-to-determine-if-a-object-type-is-a-built-in-system-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713900/how-to-determine-if-a-net-type-is-a-custom-struct).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SimplePropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class Employee { }

public class Person
{
    [SimpleProperty]
    virtual public long Code { get; set; }

    [SimpleProperty]
    virtual public string Title { get; set; }

    virtual public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(Person)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(z => z.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SimplePropertyAttribute), true).Any()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit high maintenance, though

Comment: @MarcGravell That's true, but in the other hand it might help handling some use cases, such as enumerations that are not "custom class types" (not classes at least), depending on what the OP means by "custom class types".

Comment: indeed; of course, you could argue from the fact that *in IL/CLI terminology*, enums and structs are still classes. But not in C# terminology, or via `.IsClass`

Comment: @drch I do not agree. The OP definition of "custom class type" is pretty vague, I think it's a reliable option to add an attribute to properties that meet its needs. Also, I don't think the downvote is justified.